# Is it normal to not have desktop effects after installing on an Asus N53S?

Tags: 11.10, unity, nvidia, laptop, hybrid-graphics

I've just installed 11.10 and so far so great, except I just discovered (after looking at another installation) I'm missing some effects.

First of all, I *am* using unity 3d (I chose ubuntu at the login menu), and have already the correct nvidia drivers. Yet, my launcher is the same from unity 2d, the same as the app switcher, and when dragging windows to screen corners, they don't get grabbed.

This "error" was present since the begining, so I was not able to detect it.

Please help, I want to have an ubuntu experience as nice as everyone else.

EDIT 1:

I'm using an Asus N53S. My graphic card is Nvidia geforce GT540M. It says cuda, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

540M are hybrid cards, you have a intel + nvidia card running in your system, the drivers you are installing for you nvidia are not working correctly because they are not being loaded on startup.

You Intel card is running as primary so you have 2 options:

1) If you BIOS allows to turn off the Intel card and leave the nVidia one running then the drivers will work correctly;

2) Use software that enables you to use some functions of your nVidia card, its [called Bumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work/36936#36936) and its largelly discussed on use/installation, etc, on the site.

Comment: Ok I'll check the bios and post if it has the option you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if it was suppoused to be so easy but after installing bumblebee and reloging in everything worked fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

if you like, you can install the comiz manager or CCSM as its known, its controls what effects are enabled and what ones arent't.

if you go to the software centre and search for CCSM, install it, then search CCSM in the dash and click to launch, it will give you a better idea of whether the effects you are expecting are enabled to begin with

Comment: I did it already. Everything I am complaining about is "enabled" through CCSM. : (

Comment: fair enough, its always best to check the easier options before getting dirty in case you don't need to I always say :)